# looping an array and distributing the results to three different paragraphs

Tags: javascript, html

I have an array of 0-3 name values. I need to loop through my array and write the values to 3 different `<p>` with different class names.

Not sure how to use innerHTML to assign the data values to individual divs. Plenty of info online about how to write all the data to a single div but not multiples (that i could find).

Here is the principle code...

```js
const dataResults = ['Apple', 'Orange', 'Pear']

for (var i = 0; i < dataResults.length; i++) {
  //how to distribute these results to V1, V2 and V3???
  console.log(dataResults[i]);
}
```

```html
<div class="selections">
  <p class="v1">-</p>
  <p class="v2">-</p>
  <p class="v3">-</p>
</div>
```

As a closing bonus I will also need to empty the array after it has completed its task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const dataResults = ['Apple', 'Orange', 'Pear'];
for (var i = 0; i < dataResults.length; i++) {
    document.querySelector(".v" + (i + 1)).innerHTML = dataResults[i];
}


//Additional from the comment
document.getElementById("clearBtn").addEventListener("click", function(){
  document.querySelectorAll(".v1, .v2, .v3").forEach(function(item) {
    item.innerHTML = "";
  });
});
```

```html
<div class="selections">
    <p class="v1">-</p>
    <p class="v2">-</p>
    <p class="v3">-</p>
</div>

<!--Additional from the comment -->
<button type="button" id="clearBtn">Clear</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should dynamically build selector from your loop index:

```js
const dataResults = ['Apple', 'Orange', 'Pear']

for (var i = 0; i < dataResults.length; i++) {
       el = document.querySelector('.v' + (i + 1));
       text = document.createTextNode(dataResults[i]);
       el.appendChild(text);

       console.log(dataResults[i]);
}
```

```html
<div class="selections">
  <p class="v1">-</p>
  <p class="v2">-</p>
  <p class="v3">-</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

One solution to the above problem is by storing the `<p>` tags in the list and adding the elements in it. Like:

```js
const dataResults = ['Apple', 'Orange', 'Pear']


let d = document.getElementsByClassName('selections')[0]
let p = d.children;
let count = d.childElementCount;


for (var i = 0; i < dataResults.length; i++) {
  p[i%count].innerHTML = dataResults[i]
  console.log(dataResults[i]);
}
```

```html
<div class="selections">
  <p class="v1">-</p>
  <p class="v2">-</p>
  <p class="v3">-</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Select the paragraphs and loop over them setting the text.

```js
const dataResults = ['Apple', 'Orange', 'Pear']

document.querySelectorAll(".selections p").forEach(function(p, index) {
  p.textContent = dataResults[index] || '';
});
```

```html
<div class="selections">
  <p class="v1">-</p>
  <p class="v2">-</p>
  <p class="v3">-</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make it more dynamic by using the modulo operator, so you can assign any length array items to 3 of the elements

```
const dataResults = ['Apple', 'Orange', 'Pear', 'Foo', 'Baz']

const sets = [
    [],
    [],
    []
];

// 1. sort items into sets by item index
dataResults.forEach((item, i) => {
    sets[i % 3].push(item);
});

// 2 set each p element content
sets.forEach((set, i) => {
    const node = document.querySelector(`.selections .v${i + 1}`);

    // make sure node exists, to prevent any HTML errors
    // or you could even create the P tag here to prevent any issues
    // and append that to the .selections
    if (node != null) {
        node.innerHTML = set.join(', ');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

- `querySelectorAll()` to select all `<p>`
- `item[i]` use to insert HTML text in`<p>`

```js
const dataResults = ['Apple', 'Orange', 'Pear'];
const item = document.querySelectorAll(".selections p");  

for (var i = 0; i < dataResults.length; i++) {
  item[i].innerHTML = dataResults[i];
  console.log(dataResults[i]);
}
```

```html
<div class="selections">
  <p class="v1">-</p>
  <p class="v2">-</p>
  <p class="v3">-</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Make the div elements up as you need them. This way you're not constricted to the number of elements that are present in the DOM.

Iterate over the array and produce an array of HTML strings. You can `join` those up and add them to the innerHTML of the container.

```js
const data = ['Parnsip', 'Apple', 'Orange', 'Pear', 'Peach', 'Carrot', 'Billy Joel', 'No, Mr. Bond - I expect you to die.'];

// Cache the container
const selections = document.querySelector('.selections');

// Create an array of HTML strings but make sure
// you `join` them up into one string so you can...
const html = data.map(el => `<div>${el}</div>`).join('');

// Add that HTML string to the container
selections.innerHTML = html;

// Finally empty the array
data.length = 0;
```

```html
<div class="selections"></div>
```

Additional documentation

- [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [Template/string literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)